# url rewriting htaccess 123reg

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I don't know why it seems than my htaccess rewriting url doesn't work at all on 123reg.
on ovh (my test environnement): http:www.luckyunlucky.co.uk/mvc  it work properly
on 123reg : http://www.petitmondelondon.co.uk  only the index is accessible after that I have a error 404.

my htaccess :
root :

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
RewriteBase /
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

and in public

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]


</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

it's just a nightmare please help me !?

Comment: I need more details. Is the problem occurring on one server but not the other? What are the differences between the two? How does index.php handle the URL?

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite.c` even enabled/loaded, and are you allowed by server config to use it?

Comment: Okay, some Googling tells me that 123reg is a webhost. (In future, you should clarify things like that.) The first thing you should try is putting `RewriteBase /` in both of those rulesets. It's only in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

My name is Ray and I work for 123-reg, I can see that petitmondelondon.co.uk is registered with 123-reg but is set to 301 redirect to a domain hosted with a 3rd party. If you can provide me with a support ticket number I will be able to help you point the domain to the hosting where you wish for your above code to work.